# Investigating why server became unresponsive

Tags: debian, vps

I am running a virtual private server (Debian/Linux running apache+tomcat+jruby) and from time to time it becomes unreachable (I am not even able to ping it). I blame this on our service provider. When this happens the server has to be rebooted via the provider's management console and everything is back to normal. I have tried going through the logs in var/log but found nothing extraordinary there. What are the next steps in investigation such incidents?

Answer (score 1):

It might have been helpful if you'd mentioned what you were looking for in the logs and failed to find.

There's probably not a lot you could do here. But you might try setting up a basic internal watchdog - using cron (or preferably a daemon) to fire and log events at regular, short intervals - then check if it ran continiously until the reboot.

And increase logging.

Presumably you are paying the service provider - you should be asking them to provide details of their investigation

Answer (score 1):

These are the first questions I would want to answer in order to troubleshoot the problem:

- **At the time which the server became unresponsive, did it have the ability send outgoing ping packets?**
- **How does the network configuration look at the time of the failure?**
- **Is there a firewall running on the server? What is it's state at the time of failure?**

Do you have a KVM you could use to try to establish a remote console session? In any case, you will want to see what is going on from *inside* the server at the time of failure.

When the logs do not indicate errors and when you do not have the ability to establish a remote console setting, you could settle for a `cron` entry that regularly echos output of your network/firewall settings to a file that you could check later.